# Model Django Poll

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working through the [Django tutorials](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), and now I am at creating a poll.

The code below works fine until I want to create choices, where for some reason I always get this error message:

```
line 22, in __unicode__
return self.question

AttributeError: 'Choice' object has no attribute 'question'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_today(self):
        return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()



class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question # this is line 22
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `__unicode__` method on the `Choice` model should look something like:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.poll.question
```

`question` attribute does not exist on the `Choice` model, you need to reach for it over the `poll` foreign key field.

Don't forget to check out Django's great documentation that shows many examples [on how to handle many to one relationships](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_one/).

**Edit**

It would probably make more sense to `return self.choice` in `Choice` model `__unicode__` method so it outputs the actual choice not the Poll question.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.choice
```

Comment: I did that and now I get these responses:

>>> Poll.objects.all()
[<Poll: What's up?>]
>>> Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
<Poll: What's up?>
>>> p=Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> p.choice_set.all()
[<Choice: What's up?>, <Choice: What's up?>]
>>> p.choice_set.create(choice='Not much', votes=0)
<Choice: What's up?>
>>> 

it should not have choices at the beginning, because I did not set any choices. 

Thanks for the documentation link!
I will check it.

Comment: True, i guess it would be silly to have something like `return self.poll.question` for output, try `return self.choice`

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I cant say for sure if the return.self.choice is the solution because for some other reason the main_page wont show up now. So I have to solve that and close this question for now. Thanks again! This is the best site I have encountered so far. Really helpful!

Answer (score 7):

To follow up on rebus's answer, the tutorial actually says to add different returns to each model:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

You had 'self.question' as the return for both - I'm thinking you made the same copy/paste error I did, or the tutorial previously had that error  ;-)

Comment: This is actually the "right" answer based on the tutorial. Not sure why you'd want to return the poll's question text when printing a choice instance.

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.poll.question
```

Because poll is a related model that contains the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a Human Brain error or a copy/paste error. We/You thought that both functions were same and copy-pasted the same code for both, but there was one word different in both.

replace `question` to `choice` in line 22